# Grothendieck 's question - any update?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry

This question is migrated from [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266761/grothendieck-s-question-any-update). I ask because it is still unclear to me and I did not receive an answer.

I was reading Barry Mazur's [biography](http://www-groups.dcs.st-and.ac.uk/~history/Biographies/Mazur_Barry.html) and come across this part:

*Grothendieck was exceptionally patient with me, for when we first met I knew next to nothing about algebra. In one of his first conversations with me, he raised the question (asked of him by Washnitzer) of whether a smooth proper algebraic variety defined over a real quadratic field could yield topologically different differentiable manifolds realized by the two possible imbeddings of the number field into the reals. What a perfect question, at least for me! Not that I answered it. But it was surely one of the very few algebro-geometric questions that I then had the background to appreciate. ... the question provided quite an incentive for a topologist to look at algebraic geometry. I began to learn the elements of algebraic geometry working with Mike Artin.*

(Edit: as comments pointed out this problem is partly resolved by Serre in the case of imaginary quadratic field, and there is a [post](http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/topology-that-algebra-cant-see/) by David Speyer on this. But the original real quadratic problem is still unclear)

Comment: I added the reference-request tag.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to the tagging procedure. I tried to add "algebraic geometry" but cannot. 

Comment: I believe that this question was answered in the affirmative by Jean-Pierre Serre, but no longer remember where I read that, and may be misremembering. As for the corresponding question for cohomology groups, see pg. 6 of http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0210327v1.pdf

Comment: I heard the same answer from one of my friends. But he also could not pointed out where did Serre proved that. So I am looking for a reference and a hopefully understandable proof to a first year graduate student with 1 semester's background in algebraic number theory. 

Comment: If all you want is an exposition of Serre's theorem, then David Speyer wrote up a nice account on the Secret Blogging Seminar : http://sbseminar.wordpress.com/2009/07/28/topology-that-algebra-cant-see/

Comment: @David Speyer: I see. I did not know this is available online. I will try to read this when I finished grading. 

Comment: I still do not have time to read the paper, but now everything is making sense. The question is around 1958-1959, and Serre's paper is around 1964. 

Comment: For another solution to the (refined) question , you can have a look at:

 François Charles, Conjugate varieties with distinct real cohomology algebras J. Reine Angew. Math. 630 (2009), pp. 125--139.



Comment: I added the tag for algebraic geometry; a problem might have been that you did not include the prefix. Tags corresponding to math arxiv categories have a two letter prefix (and only those have one).  

Comment: In Serre's example, the base field is the Hilbert class field of an imaginary quadratic field. Is there an example with a real quadratic field?

Comment: Will an email to Professor Mazur be offensive? 